# Is anybody using juju for mission critical apps?

Tags: juju

I've been playing with juju for the last month and it is really awesome but it feels like a black box. It feels like something that I "just have to trust that it will work".

I'm very tempted to use it in my company but as awesome as juju is, it just feels like it is very new and not "proven to work" in mission critical environments. Of course, I may be completely wrong...

Is there anybody out ther really using juju? Not testing and playing with it but really deploying aplications into production environment with it?

Comment: Sorry but, what's the problem with using juju?

Comment: @Braiam there is absolutely NO problem with using juju. I'm just asking if anyone is using juju to control their production infrastructure. Or if, at the stage that juju is right now, it is simply a promising tool.

Comment: Ok, first, try always asking for *problems you are facing* or explications of how/why things works in Y or X way. Your question as it's now it will only invites opinions. I can answer with "Juju has been great for the two months I've used it" or "Juju made me lose 6 months of work just migrating stuff". The only answers will be entirely based on personal experiences of any answerer. You should instead test it yourself in your development environment and see how it goes, or ask for stuff that you might be interested in the functionality of Juju or how-to-do-X, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In so many words, yes. There's really nothing black box about what Juju is doing. Everything Juju does is Open Source and the model juju is using is fairly well documented. There are fairly large companies using Juju to deploy and manage OpenStack on bare metal with MaaS and deploying workloads on their OpenStack (again, with juju).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Marco. Actually, when I say black box, I'm not referring about the open source nature of juju. Of course that anybody can become an expert and completely understand juju. I'm talking about the lack of charm documentation. For instance, I cannot find anywhere how to deploy a highly available RabbitMQ cluster with mirrored queues (or even the information if this is possible at all). I'm very tempted to simply trow away Chef and replace it with juju but the lack of documentation scares me a little bit.

Comment: So you're right, [some of the charms](http://manage.jujucharms.com/precise/rabbitmq-server) are really poorly documented. We're in the process of a huge audit of the charm store which will include, among other things, updating the READMEs for all charms currently in the store. Rabbitmq-server is currently being worked on so this will include making sure it conforms to charm store policy, updated readme, and tests

Comment: Marco, do you know where is the best place to post a question to the actual developer of a charm? Should I create an account at launchpad and post questions there? Or should I post charm related questions here?

Comment: Questions can be posted here, but the author may or may not be following on Ask Ubuntu. It's best to post bugs against the bug link on the charm page or email the maintainer directly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Canonical has many production services running using Juju.

There are other companies that we know about too that are also running production services with Juju.